# How can I keep a steady voltage from car battery to power a switch even when battery voltage drops?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, automotive, battery-operated, ups

I have a customized car with 2 engines.  I have no mechanical door opening system for the doors as I have removed it in favor of a remote-controlled electrical solenoid.  I have recently installed a capacitive switch to be able to open the doors without the remote.  Since I have the switch hooked up to the rear engine battery (that is not the car's primary drive engine), the battery tends to drop over time through non-use.  I was wondering if there is a way to hook up some sort of ups system in the car so that the switch will work even if the battery drops too low (this has happened).  I have a solar trickle recharger on order to try and help this problem, but I would like a more stable system to be able to open the doors.

Comment: A diode and a battery?

Comment: how much voltage do your switches need?
If it's less than 10.5V, you can't really do anything.
An empty battery is still empty, even when you apply some circuit around it.

Comment: Yeah, a large diode system allowing the secondary battery to charge from the alternator sounds like it would work. I'm very curious about how you end up with 2 engines and what the second one is for though!

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as @pjc50... Anyway, Lead-Acid batteries are supposed to have very low self-discharge (it takes from 6 to 12 months to go from 100% to 50% capacity). So the statement "the battery tends to drop over time through non-use" makes me wonder: How much time, exactly? What is the battery capacity? Is there some standby load on this battery? If yes, how much?

Comment: What is the operating voltage of the switch?

Comment: https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15193608_1263424020370240_8120864844400078297_n.jpg?oh=4c095085ee5a50ef4095b6fe6f997de5&oe=58D781C8

Comment: They are each front-wheel drive 500CI engines.  Each engine drives an axle.  The vehicle is all wheel drive, 4-wheel steering.  Generally the car drives on the front engine with the rear locked in neutral due to us not yet figuring out how to link the brakes and front wheel steering.•Power supply Switch requirements:
◦6V-30V DC
◦Current capability sufficient to drive the total of all output loads

Comment: Impressive. But I really hope you don't plan to drive that on an open road, though...

Comment: @dim I need to do some more investigation on what is drawing power from the battery.  The rear engine is a complete unit with the full wiring harness.  I suspect there is some sort of magnetic field from the drag of the offline engine moving constantly in neutral. Or a transmission sensor.  Top of the line technology from 1972.  We DO drive this on the road.  It is street legal.  Even passes MA vehicle inspection.

Comment: Not weird at all. Car & Driver mag did the same thing with a Honda CRX in 1984.  They just spiked the rear steering. 3-wire alternators have a draw when in "run".  Get a modern 1-wire alternator and that should solve that.  I take it 2 separate batteries? I have 1-battery system and generator 1 overloads when you start engine 2.

Comment: An automotive store will have a "Battery Isolator" to keep an auxiliary battery charged from one alternator. Install one for each alternator, two in your case. A wire from an alternator and output to two batteries. They have adequate current carrying capacity and secure mountings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should charge both batteries when either or at least the main engine is running.  Add a Schottky diode in series between each battery and the altenator output.  If you can, adjust the altenator output up a few 100 mV to compensate for the Schottky diode voltage drop.

Another possibility is to use a relay to short the batteries together once the main engine is running.  Deciding "running" isn't as easy as it may sound, but the advantage is that there won't be any voltage drop between the altenator and the charging batteries.

Once both batteries are being regularly charged, you shouldn't need separate power to cover the case when the back battery is dead.  Regularly deep-discharging a lead acid battery, especially one intended for a car, is not good.  That will ruin its capacity, and make it vulnerable to low temperatures.

Comment: We were worried about doing that and what the effect would be if both alternators were running at the same time.  Wouldn't we need some way to ensure that too much current isn't being pushed to a single battery?  Or would the load from both batteries be sufficient on their own?

Comment: @Matt: Then put a Schottky diode from each alternator to each battery, a total of 4 diodes.  That way both batteries get charged when either engine is running, but the two alternators are still isolated from each other.  The batteries will also be isolated when the engines are off.